# React Axios post request is getting timed out after 4 minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios

Building React app. Using Axios to upload file. Simple post request with FormData and multipart/form-data header is getting time out after 4 minutes in Chrome and 2 minutes in Safari.
As backend I'm using Django.
In dev environment I'm using proxy parameter in package.json to connect to backend via localhost.
As production environment I'm building static files via npm run build command and Django is serving them directly without any proxy like nginx.

The issue is present in local/dev and production environment.
Need help as I'm getting insane here, as any work around is not working.

Thanks in advance.

```js
loadData = () => {

        let formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append('file', this.state.file);
          
        let path = `/path`
        this.setState({loading: true});

        axios(path, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: formData
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok!
It was quite a while since post but I figured it out. Apparently it was timeout configured on Gunicorn it was exactly 120 sec. Why it was longer on Chrome? No idea but this difference between Chrome and rest of the browser threw me in the wrong direction.
So yea, fixed.